# How to prevent html code from appearing at end of exported excel workbook

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am trying to export data from a SQL Server Database to an excel workbook on a webpage using vb.net.

I am using the streamwriter method, this is the format of my code:

```
Dim x As StreamWriter
Dim fileName As String = "test.xls"
Dim output As String = "C:/...."
tWriter = New StreamWriter(output)
For Each row As DataRow In datatable.Rows
tWriter.Write(....)
...
Next

tWriter.Flush()
tWriter.Dispose()
tWriter.Close()

Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & fileName)
Response.WriteFile(output)
Response.Flush()
Response.End()
```

The issue I am having is that the html code for the webpage is appearing at the end of the xls file. I am unclear as to why this is or how to get rid of it.

The webpage produces the excel file on a button press and sends it as an attachment to the browser.

Does anyone have any ideas? I have tried multiple content types and they all produce the same results.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and the following changes fixed it for me:

1st i changed `Response.AppendHeader` to `Response.AddHeader` and i changed `Response.WriteFile(output)` to `Response.Write(output)`

Comment: Thanks for answering, when I change Response.WriteFile(output) to Response.Write(output) the xls is only showing the webpage, without any styles. the appendHeader to AddHEader change didn't make a difference.